# Is it possible for a dhclient-script exit hook script to hide a dhclient non-zero return code?

Tags: linux, dhcp

With dhclient, my understanding is that exit hooks in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/*` are sourced and run after dhclient completes. Because they are sourced, is there a chance that they could be hiding a non-zero return code from dhclient itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dhclient-script` handles exit codes in such a way that hook exit codes only override the main exit code if they are non-zero.

So, if `dhclient` succeeds, but a hook returns an exit code other than 0, that exit code is used as the overall exit code. If `dhclient` fails, but in a scenario where exit hooks are still run, then the exit code will reflect either the `dhclient` error, or a hook error; successful exit hooks won’t replace the non-zero exit code set previously.

You should be able to determine whether this is happening by looking at your logs: when a hook returns a non-zero exit code, [it’s logged](https://salsa.debian.org/dhcp-team/isc-dhcp/blob/d0d58776805d720029619ea06df5c57706eecd5a/debian/dhclient-script.linux#L150).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is the reverse true, though? If you run `dhclient` with the `-1` opt so that any dhclient failures result in a non-zero exit code, could a handler effectively "hide" a non-zero return code by returning 0?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I got the question mixed up while working out the answer. I’ve updated my answer to address your real question.